# Using the Flickr API how can I get back the absolute path to an image?

Tags: php, html, image, api, flickr

Ok, this is not only how to get the URL to an image, it is a little more than that and I proceed to explain trying to be as clear as possible, I might point out that I am a totally newbie on this, I am a PHP Junior programmer and this is my first time using Flickr at all:

I have PHP website online, I have done all what is related to Key, Secret, Token and that. So basically I have a public image uploader that works fine. You could go into my website pick a picture and upload them to my Flickr account.

Now, they PHP for doing that is basically this one:

```
$apiKey = "(my API Key)";
$apiSecret = "(my API Secret)";
$permissions  = "write";
$token        = "(my Token)";

$f = new phpFlickr($apiKey, $apiSecret, true);
$f->setToken($token);
$f->sync_upload($path, $title);
return $f;
```

The phpFlickr object comes in the Flickr API, and $f in this case gives me back an array with the picture ID and some other data.

How can I get an absoulte path to the just uploaded picture in the form www.flickr.com/something/myPicture.jpg in order to build a  HTML tag?

Probably what $f gives me is not enough. Any light over this would be great!

Hope it was clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just found how. In case anyone is interested:

```
$f = new phpFlickr($apiKey, $apiSecret, true);
$f->photos_getInfo(PHOTO_ID);
```

That gives you back an array with all what you need to complete the URL.

Comment: but this is output "Array" for me?

Answer (score 0):

Before I start writing, take a look at these links. They might have what you're looking for:

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.getInfo.html

If you're trying to build an absolute path to a photo, you have to build the entire path based on the information that you get from a successful API call which is going to be located in $f. Looking at the first link I posted, there are a few ways to build an absolute path for a picture given that you have all of the information needed. The first method is to build the photo source URL, which comes in this format:

> `http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}.jpg`
>
> or
>
> `http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}_[mstzb].jpg`
>
> or
>
> `http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{o-secret}_o.(jpg|gif|png)`

The information required to build these links can be found in a successful call to the photos.getInfo API call that I posted above. Building the absolute path is as simple as just combining all of the variables together:

(I haven't touched PHP in a while, bear with me)

`my $link = 'http://farm' . $farmid . '.staticflickr.com/' . $serverid . '/' . $id . '_' . $secret . '.jpg';`

The second method is to build the webpage URL. This can either be grabbed directly from the photos.getinfo API call, or built manually given that you have the user-id and/or photo-id. If you have the required information, building the link is almost the same as the way I did it above. Check out the first link I posted for the actual URLs you need to build.

One last thing I should mention is that you should make sure that your API calls are working. I spent so much wasted time back when I was first learning how to use API's because I never checked the output of what the API calls were returning or my authentication was incorrect. Doing a vardump($f) (or something similar) and seeing what the calls are returning might help you visualize what needs to be done to get the information you need.

Comment: Your answer is great, certainly it has all what I need. Thanks for that. However, and this may be more a PHP question: How should I use the flickr.photos.getInfo in my PHP? Sorry if my question is too newbie, but it will help me alot if you could post a PHP chunk, just one line, no worries if the syntaxis is not the best one.

Comment: It seems like you figured it out already, but are you asking me how to make an API call, or how to retrieve information from the result using PHP?

Comment: I guess it was a combination of both. I was not sure about the PHP either. My memory and my amateur...ness didn't help. But now it is clear to me thanks to your answer. Thank you!